# String Replace problem

Tags: java, string, replace, java-6

**What I have:**

I've got a text `"Hi {0}, my name is {1}."`

I've got a `List<String> names = Arrays.asList("Peter", "Josh");`

I'm trying to fit Peter where there's a {0} and Josh where there's a {1}.

**What I want:**

```
Hi Peter, my name is Josh.
```

Any ideas of how could I do it?

Comment: What environment and/or programming language are you using?

Comment: You need *a lot* more detail here if you want a reasonable answer.

Comment: Syntax looks like `c#`; so I retagged it.

Comment: woohh!!! good to know that `Java` has almost same syntax as `c#`

Comment: When there is an existing class that does your work for you, you should use it instead of using String.replace .. MessageFormat can format complex messages and accept the string pattern you want to use.

Comment: Why do you start counting at 1? Why not `{0}` and `{1}`? That would be so much better in my eyes.

Comment: I've switched it on my application. But thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably simplest would be to use one of the String.replaceXX ops in a loop.  Eg,

```
String sourceString = "Hi {1}, my name is {2}."
for (i = 0; i < names.size(); i++) {
    String repText = names.get(i);
    sourceString = sourceString.replace("{" + (i+1) + "}", repText);
}
```

This is a bit inefficient, since it's bad form to repeatedly create new Strings vs using a StringBuffer or some such, but generally text replacement of this form would be a low-frequency operation, so simplicity trumps efficiency.

Comment: Though it does indeed look like MessageFormat is the way to go.  I learned java before java.text existed, so I'll claim justifiable ignorance.

Answer (score 8):

MessageFormat class is your friend. http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html

```
                String aa = "Hi {0}, my name is {1}";

            Object[] bb = {"Peter" , "John"};

            System.out.println(MessageFormat.format(aa, bb));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
List<String> names = new ArrayList<String();
names.add("Peter");
names.add("Josh");
String str = "Hi {1}, my name is {2}.";
str = str.replaceFirst("{1}", names.get(0));
str = str.replaceFirst("{2}", names.get(1));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String text = "Hi {1}, my name is {2}.";
java.util.List<String> names = Arrays.asList("Peter", "Josh");
for(String s: names) text = text.replace("{" + (names.indexOf(s) + 1) + "}", s);
```

Answer (score 1):

You would do something like this.

```
List<String> names = Arrays.asList("Peter", "Josh");
System.out.printf("Hi %s, my name is %s.", names.get(0), names.get(1));
```

and that would be it in just 2 lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
names.add("Peter");
names.add("Josh");
System.out.println("Hi " + names.get(0) + ", my name is " + names.get(1) + ".");
```

My apologies if I'm taking you too literally and you wanat something more generic but this will do exactly as you asked.

Comment: Good except he wants to replace {1} with names.get(0) and the same for {2}

Comment: it's not dynamic, i want it to be dynamic, what happens if it has the third element?

Comment: @pringlesinn in that case give us a little more information. Using for loops to access the full length of the List allows you to dynamically grow your print statement. Give me more information and I'll gladly provide you a more generic answer. EDIT: You may just want to look at [the JavaDoc for List](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/List.html) to understand how you can make this more dynamic. Look at methods like "contains" or "indexOf"

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that your list will have the correct number of elements.

```
`String s = "Hi {1}, my name is {2}.";`
for(int x = 1;x <= names.size();x++)
{
   s.replaceFirst("{" + x +"}",names.get(x - 1));
}
```